# Run Batch File as Administrator using RunOnce

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a program installed on various machines, which needs a manual update.

I have all of the updated files stored on a share on a server, and have written a batch file that will copy these into the correct local directory (Program Files (x86))

My plan is to deploy a group policy which will execute this batch file on RunOnce, updating the program when the users first log in.

The problem is to write to the directory, I have to run the batch file as Administrator.

How can I do this using RunOnce? Is there another way?

I've tried using RoboCopy, but just get "Access Denied" and the same problem.

Below is my batch file code.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\\." (goto CopyNetHelp) else Goto ExitLoop

:CopyNetHelp

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\nethdclient.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\NetHelpDeskClientUpdater.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\nhescalatorclient.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

:ExitLoop

﻿Exit
```

Comment: A startup script might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (GOTO askAdmin)
GOTO gotAdmin
:askAdmin
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:: batch is being ran as admin
:skipAdmin

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\\." (goto CopyNetHelp) else Goto ExitLoop

:CopyNetHelp

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\nethdclient.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\NetHelpDeskClientUpdater.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\nhescalatorclient.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

:ExitLoop

﻿Exit
```

Comment: This works if the bat file is local. Not so if it's run from the network.

Comment: I managed to get this to work by copying it into the users documents folder which doesn't require admin permission. It is then called from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future searches, this is how I got it to work.
I created a new batch file. This will be the one run from RunOnce.
This simply copies the "real" batch file into the users document folder if required. It then calls that batch file from the document folder, thus running it locally getting around the issue.

The "real" batch file as posted by Dennis then runs and once finished, deletes itself from the documents folder.

Copy Batch

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\\." (goto CopyNetHelp) else Goto ExitLoop
:CopyNetHelp
copy "\\server\data\pc_support\UpdateNetHelpAdmin.bat" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" /y

"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\UpdateNetHelpAdmin.bat"

:ExitLoop
Exit
```

"Real" batch file

```
@echo off


>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (GOTO askAdmin)
GOTO gotAdmin
:askAdmin
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:: batch is being ran as admin
:skipAdmin

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\\." (goto CopyNetHelp) else Goto ExitLoop

:CopyNetHelp

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\nethdclient.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\NetHelpDeskClientUpdater.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y

COPY "\\server\programs\Nethelpdesk\NetHelpUpgrade\NhEscalatorClient.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetHelpDesk\" /y


del "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\UpdateNetHelpAdmin.bat" /q


:ExitLoop

del "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\UpdateNetHelpAdmin.bat" /q

Exit
```